# Scrapy request not going through

Tags: web-scraping, dynamic, python-requests, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I don't know how to frame this question exactly. I am beginner at web scraping and I am trying to crawl a website using Python Scrapy. The website is dynamic and uses javascript and can't retrieve any data using the basic level xpath and CSS selectors.

I am trying to mimic the API request through my spider by requesting the url which has the data in json object. That request url is throwing a HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed error.
I think I am calling the wrong URL. 9/10 times this method of calling the json object url directly has worked for me. What can I do different?
the url has parameters and form data items in the headers section and the url doesn't even look like a valid website url
it starts with https://ih3kc909gb-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes....
I know this is a long question but I could really use some help with how to get a response for this?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking website. can you provide the url?

Comment: https://ih3kc909gb-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/All_Carswitch_Cars/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.33.0)%3B%20Browser&x-algolia-application-id=IH3KC909GB&x-algolia-api-key=493a9bbc57331df3b278fa39c1dd8f2d

Comment: 404 error, Are you able to open the website in your browser with the same url?

Comment: This is the url I am trying to request. It is throwing the HTTP status not handled error. I don't know what could I do to parse this as I am a newbie in web scraping. All I know understood is that it is a post request, I can see the request header, the query string parameters, and form data which has a query string

Comment: https://carswitch.com/uae/used-cars/search

Comment: This is the url I actually want to get data from. The other one I found by checking how the request is going through for this url

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: start_urls = ["https://carswitch.com/uae/used-cars/search"]
       def parse(self, response):
        print("In method 1")
        url = "https://ih3kc909gb-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/All_Carswitch_Cars/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.33.0)%3B%20Browser&x-algolia-application-id=IH3KC909GB&x-algolia-api-key=493a9bbc57331df3b278fa39c1dd8f2d"
        headers= {
            "Host": "https://carswitch.com/assets/js/listing-page-min.js?v=400",
            "Referer": "https://www.carswitch.com/",
            "Origin" : "https://www.carswitch.com/",

Comment: "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
            }

Comment: I have defined the main link in the start_urls and then in the parse function I am trying to access the JSON object link that I found for the website. and defining the headers for the same

Comment: params = { "query":"",  "hitsPerPage": "24",  "page": "0", "numericFilters:["country_id=1","used_car = 1"]', "facetFilters":"", "typoTolerance":"", "tagFilters": [], "attributesToHighlight": [],

Comment: yield FormRequest(url, method = "POST", headers=headers, callback = self.parse_url, body=json.dumps(params), dont_filter = True)

Comment: And I have passed the params and headers in the request function

Comment: But I am not sure if I have passed on the details correctly, and if the request is right

Comment: I have posted the solution which returns the JSON data.

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Sure, check it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I can see the JSON data. Thanks a lot. How did the start_urls vs start_requests make the difference? Could you explain a bit or any resource where I can get more clarity on this?

Comment: If you want to pass only links then you can go with start_urls. But, if you want pass other arguments like in this case start_requests method should be used. Moreover, start_urls by default call the parse function while in later you have to call explicitly. For more details, you can can go through the link provided in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `start_requests()` method instead of `start_urls` property. You can read more about it from [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) . Now, all you need to do is to make a POST request.

**Code**

```
import scrapy

class carswitch(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'car'

    headers = {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Origin": "https://carswitch.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Referer": "https://carswitch.com/",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

    body = '{"params":"query=&hitsPerPage=24&page=0&numericFilters=%5B%22country_id%3D1%22%2C%22used_car%20%3D%201%22%5D&facetFilters=&typoTolerance=&tagFilters=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%22make%22%2C%22make_ar%22%2C%22model%22%2C%22model_ar%22%2C%22year%22%2C%22trim%22%2C%22displayTrim%22%2C%22colorPaint%22%2C%22bodyType%22%2C%22salePrice%22%2C%22transmissionType%22%2C%22GPS%22%2C%22carID%22%2C%22inspectionID%22%2C%22inspectionStatus%22%2C%22rate%22%2C%22certified_dealer_id%22%2C%22dealer_category%22%2C%22used_car%22%2C%22new%22%2C%22top_condition%22%2C%22featured%22%2C%22photo%22%2C%22modifiedPlace%22%2C%22city%22%2C%22mileage%22%2C%22urgent_sales%22%2C%22price_dropped%22%2C%22urgent_sales_days%22%2C%22urgent_sales_end_date%22%2C%22date%22%2C%22negotiable%22%2C%22oldPrice%22%2C%22zero_downpayment%22%2C%22cashOnly%22%2C%22hasPriceGuidance%22%2C%22dealerOffer%22%2C%22maxPrice%22%2C%22fairPrice%22%2C%22pricey_deal%22%2C%22fair_deal%22%2C%22good_deal%22%2C%22great_deal%22%2C%22dealership_info%22%2C%22logo_small%22%2C%22GCCspecs%22%2C%22country%22%2C%22export%22%2C%22monthly_price%22%5D"}'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://ih3kc909gb-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/All_Carswitch_Cars/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.33.0)%3B%20Browser&x-algolia-application-id=IH3KC909GB&x-algolia-api-key=493a9bbc57331df3b278fa39c1dd8f2d'    

        yield Request(url=url, method='POST', headers=self.headers, body=self.body, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self,response):

        print(response.body)
```